# errors occur while adding features with openlayers3

Tags: openlayers

I'm using openlayers v3.17.1 along with OSM Server as tile server.

I got errors when I called `vectorSource.addFeatures` with the parameter Array containing more than about 10 features.

Error Info:  **TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null** with the following code:

```
zoom_level = 10;
var FEATURE_URI = {
  1: '/marker/blue.png',
  2: '/marker/yellow.png',
  3: '/marker/red.png',
  4: '/marker/blue.png',
}

// feature alert
function Alert(f_lon, f_lat, o_alert) {
  var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([f_lon, f_lat])),
    name: o_alert.name,
    msg: o_alert.msg,
  });

  feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      opacity: .6,
      src: FEATURE_URI[o_alert.level],
      scale: 1 / 16,    // 32px
    })
  }));

  return feature;
}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: []
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM({
        url: host + '/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        crossOrigin: null,
      })
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]),
    zoom: zoom_level
  })
});

var element = $('#popup')[0];
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
  element: element,
  positioning: 'bottom-center',
  stopEvent: false,
  offset: [0, -30]
})

map.addOverlay(popup);

map.on('click', function (evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function (feature) {
      return feature;
    });
  if (feature) {
    var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    popup.setPosition(coordinates);
    $(element).popover({
      'placement': 'top',
      'html': true,
      'title': feature.get('name'),
      'content': feature.get('msg')
    });
    $(element).popover('show');
  } else {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
  }
});

// change mouse cursor when over marker
map.on('pointermove', function (e) {
  if (e.dragging) {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
    return;
  }
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
  map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});


var features = [];
// points is the Array returned from server.
points.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  if(idx > 32) return;
  var loc = val.Location.split(',');
  features[idx] = new Alert(
    +loc[0] + idx / 45,
    +loc[1],
    val
  )
});
vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
```

Answer (score 1):

All Right, using the ol-debug.js, I got the point.

It's because of the missing of img src in `FEATURE_URI`.